# CodeIgniter: query with multiple lines

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a perfectly fine query, that works when I use it in my database but not in CodeIgniter. The query looks like this

```
SET @student_id = 1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_beschikbare_data (datum_tijd) VALUES ('22/22/2222');
SET @bd_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO tbl_student_beschikbare_data (student_id,bd_id) VALUES(@student_id, @bd_id);
```

This is what i have in CodeIgniter:

```
public function save($t){

$this->db->query("SET @student_id = 1;INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_beschikbare_data (datum_tijd) VALUES ('".$t."');SET @bd_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();INSERT INTO tbl_student_beschikbare_data (student_id,bd_id) VALUES(@student_id, @bd_id);
"); }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: You cannot execute 3 queries in the same statement. Just split your queries in more than 1 $this->db->query();

Answer (score 1):

Well figured it out.. works perfectly

```
public function save($datum_tijd) {

 $this->db->query("SET @student_id = 1;"); 

$this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_beschikbare_data (datum_tijd) VALUES ('".$datum_tijd."');"); 

$this->db->query("SET @bd_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();"); 
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_student_beschikbare_data (student_id,bd_id) VALUES(@student_id, @bd_id);");

 }
```

Comment: it's giving me an error: ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1```